# Creating a UIViewController subclass vs creating an object controller in the NIB file

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xib

I am going through a tutorial walkthrough that requires me to create a controller object in the NIB file, the controller object has class outlets and class actions which are then interconnected with the User interface objects such as label,button etc. The tutorial is for an earlier version of XCode. The Xcode version that I have is the latest version and there are certain things that are non obvious to me in this.
At first it requires me to add class outlets and class actions in the identity inspector for the controller object. However, in my Xcode, I am unable to find a panel that let's me carry out the aforementioned tasks. Given this, I am lost in my Xcode as to how I can carry the task out.

This also created more confusion for me as to why the tutorial does not let me create a UIViewController subclass, from which I can create the necessary outlets and actions and then interconnect through the file's owner.

The above sums up in two questions,

1. How in Xcode 4.3 can one specify class outlets and actions through the identity inspector for a controller object present in the NIB file?  (or through any other alternative?)
2. What is the difference between a controller object that one creates in the NIB file vs a UIViewController subclass that acts as the controller class?

I understand this is a little fuzzy, but hopefully I am getting my point across. Looking forward to people's answers.

Thanks much!

Parijat !

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the controller object to get this pop-up:

[image]

Comment: that is very helpful, still curious to know what the difference between creating a UIViewController Subclass and a controller object is? Thanks much !

Comment: A controller object is a generic controller object and a view controller is a type of controller.  A bit hard to explain, and you rarely need to use a generic controller.  Here is more from Apple:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CustomObject.html